# Do you have any geography restrictions to connect to Azure GCC or GCC High cloud infrastructure

Tags: azure

I would like to know if azure has any network region specific restrictions to connect to Azure GCC or GCC High cloud infrastructure

Comment: What exactly do you mean with  "network region specific restricitions"?

Comment: Hi Florian, I mean if there is any restriction for accessing Azure GCC or GCC High Cloud from outside US